# German horror movie with a surgeon and interns performing surgeries on themselves

Tags: story-identification, movie

I can't remember the title of this German movie from around 2010 I guess. An intern is accepted in a hospital with a famous surgeon who is followed by a clique of interns. They perform surgeries in themselves, grafting new muscles to their bodies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it the movie [Anatomy 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomy_(film)) or [Anatomy 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomy_2)? But it should be the second one. On the german wikipedia page there is this plot description:

> Die geheime Vereinigung mit jungen Ärzten arbeitet im OP 17 an einem spektakulären Projekt – synthetische Muskeln. Schon bald ist Jo in die Entwicklungen des Professors eingeweiht. Die synthetischen Muskeln bieten nicht nur die Chance, Patienten wie seinem Bruder das Gehen zu ermöglichen, sondern sie können die Leistungen sogar auf übermenschliches Niveau heben. Wie auch seine Kommilitonen Viktoria, Sven, Gregor und Hagen zuvor, lässt sich Jo die künstlichen Muskeln einsetzen, um die Implantate durch Selbstversuche zu testen und das Projekt voranzutreiben.

which translates to (via Google Translate)

> The secret association with young doctors is working on a spectacular project in the OP 17 - synthetic muscles. Soon Jo is inaugurated in the developments of the professor. The synthetic muscles not only provide a chance for patients like his brother to walk, but they can even raise their performance to superhuman levels. Like his fellow students Viktoria, Sven, Gregor and Hagen before, Jo uses the artificial muscles to self-test the implants and drive the project forward.

Comment: Yes, it's the second one. I watched the Anatomy movie trailer. It was close, but did not ring a favorable bell, so I didn't check the second one before asking my question. Thank you!